# Ocultar rangos de celdas en Excel con VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Estaría interesado en ocultar filas en hoja excel antes de imprimir, tengo un código con error

Me podrían dar ayuda ?

```
Sub OcultarFilas()

    Dim Celda As Range
    Hoja1.Select 
    while Celda == Range("A1:W393")
        If Celda.Value = 0 || Empty(Celda) Then
            Rows(Celda.Row & ":" & Celda.Row) = True
        End If
    Hoja1.PrintPreview

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes probar así

Creo que estas mezclando varios lenguajes. Cambia || por Or

```
Sub OcultarFilas()

    Dim Celda As Range
    Hoja1.Select 'seleccionas por nombre del objeto
    For Each Celda In Range("A1:W393")   'usa un For Each
        If Celda.Value = 0 Or IsEmpty(Celda) Then 'si esta vacía o con cero la oculta
            Rows(Celda.Row & ":" & Celda.Row).EntireRow.Hidden = True  'Agrega la parte final del código
        End If
    Next Celda  'pasa a la siguiente
    Hoja1.PrintPreview

End Sub
```

Comment: Vaya, que rapido, muchas gracias. Lo pruebo